# Passing variable between Scripts using Script Parameter in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, sqlplus

I am running following install.sql in ORACLE SQL Command Prompt and pass the three parameter values ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID and schema PWD

```
---- Start of install.sql

--parameter 1: ${ORACLE_HOME}
--parameter 2: ${ORACLE_SID}
--parameter 3: ${PRDPASS}


set define on

prompt
prompt ======================================
prompt ||  Database Creation Started       ||
prompt ======================================
prompt 


prompt create prd_adminus objects................

connect prd_adminus/&3;

prompt Variable 1 = &1
prompt Variable 2 = &2
prompt Variable 3 = &3



@createSQLObjects.sql &1 &2 &3

prompt
prompt  Loading Java Classes for prd_adminus
prompt  ================================
prompt
connect prd_adminus/&3;

@loadjavaclasses.sql &1 &2 &3


prompt
prompt  Completed Loading Java Classes for prd_adminus
prompt  =============================================
prompt

prompt
prompt  Applying patch
prompt  ..............


@patch1.sql &1 &2 &3  
@patch2.sql &1 &2 &3 
@patch3.sql &1 &2 &3  

prompt
prompt ======================================
prompt ||  Database Creation Completed   ||
prompt ======================================
prompt 

disconnect;
exit;

---- End of install.sql
```

The substitute values are working fine until `@patch2.sql &1 &2 &3`

While running `@patch3.sql` the values of the variables are reset and patch3.sql terminates. This is due to `Set Define Off` specified inside `patch2.sql` to avoid the `&` in the scripts.

Is there any other ways to retain my values &1 , &2 and &3

Comment: Why did you tag sql-server?

Comment: is `set define on` being run in patch2.sql at the end? Alternatively, assuming the &'s are as part of a string, you could change them to `chr(38)`, e.g.: `SELECT 'T'||CHR(38)||'Cs' FROM dual;`?

Comment: Just add `set define on` before running `patch3.sql`